# Texture Paint: Color shows different on the mesh

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting, color

I just started painting a mesh and for a while it worked OK, but now when I paint on the UV map, the color doesn't show as I chose.

Before:

[image: Before]

After I painted on the door:

[image: After]

Comment: Can you share the blend file?

Comment: No, I don't press CTRL. Here's the blend file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=5672" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/5672/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the viewport shading type to **Material**.

[image]